TypeError when trying to multiply two Qobj in Qutip
I am starting out with learning Qutip and was going through the tutorial and introduction examples on their website. However, I am running into the following Type error when I tried to run a function that calculates the commutator of two operators my code
error message
i get the same error when I try to multiple two operators, so I think its an issue with multiplication.
error from multiplication
Note: I ran the same code on google colab and it ran without any problem. But when I ran it locally on pycharm and jupyter lab, I get this error. Could some please help me resolve this. Thank you!
I tried searching these errors on google and also tried chatgpt, but wasn't able to resolve it. I have tried reinstalling python, jupyter and qutip, and made sure I ws using the right version of python and numpy required by qutip. But the error still persists

Please read How do I ask a good question?. Under 'Help others reproduce the problem' it emphasizes in a bold bullet point not to use screenshots to share code and error reports. You had the text of the code, just put it in the post as a fenced code blocks. Similar with error. The screenshots aren't useable by those trying to help you and the Stackoverflow system cannot make connections between related posts as the indexing needs text. As for you issue, you mention Pyhton & numpy, did you look at what versions of everything else was involved?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
